# error in .bashrc file Linux bash: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: line 217: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu 20.04 and can someone tell me what is the solution of the following problem :-
``` bash: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: line 217: syntax error near unexpected token ``done ```

`bash: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: line 217:`      `done'`
[image]

My .bashrc file is as follows :-

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
#shubhi aliases :-

#shubhi directories:-
alias friends="cd ~/friends/"
alias d="cd ~/Desktop/"
alias cu="cd ~/Desktop/shubhi/ShubhiCUWorksheets/semester2/"
alias oop="cd ~/Desktop/shubhi/ShubhiCUWorksheets/semester2/ooplab"
alias de="cd ~/Desktop/shubhi/ShubhiCUWorksheets/semester2/delab"
alias iot="cd ~/Desktop/shubhi/ShubhiCUWorksheets/semester2/iotlab"
alias cw="cd ~/Desktop/shubhi/ShubhiCUWorksheets/semester2/computerworkshop"
alias songs="cd ~/Desktop/shubhi/shubhi_songs"
alias c="clear"
alias s="cd ~/Desktop/shubhi"
alias p="cd ~/Desktop/shubhi/python"
alias r="cd ~/Desktop/shubhi/Rap"
alias bh="cd ~/Desktop/shubhi/shubhi_bootcamp/html_bootcamp"
alias bp="cd ~/Desktop/shubhi/shubhi_bootcamp/python_bootcamp"
alias a="cd ~/Desktop/shubhi/csall"
alias doo="cd ~/Downloads"
#volume booster:-
alias v1="pactl set-sink-volume 1 120%"
alias v2="pactl set-sink-volume 1 150%"
alias v3="pactl set-sink-volume 1 200%"
alias v4="pactl set-sink-volume 1 250%"
alias v5="pactl set-sink-volume 1 300%"


#shubhi
alias 5m="sleep 5m && play ~/Desktop/shubhi/shubhi_songs/'Alarm Clock For Heavy Sleepers (Loud)-fpQHabt6e-w.mp3'"
alias 10m="sleep 10m && play ~/Desktop/shubhi/shubhi_songs/'Alarm Clock For Heavy Sleepers (Loud)-fpQHabt6e-w.mp3'"
alias 20m="sleep 20m && play ~/Desktop/shubhi/shubhi_songs/'Alarm Clock For Heavy Sleepers (Loud)-fpQHabt6e-w.mp3'"
alias 30m="sleep 30m && play ~/Desktop/shubhi/shubhi_songs/'Alarm Clock For Heavy Sleepers (Loud)-fpQHabt6e-w.mp3'"
alias 1m="sleep 1m && play ~/Desktop/shubhi/shubhi_songs/'Alarm Clock For Heavy Sleepers (Loud)-fpQHabt6e-w.mp3'"
alias 1h="sleep 1h && play ~/Desktop/shubhi/shubhi_songs/'Alarm Clock For Heavy Sleepers (Loud)-fpQHabt6e-w.mp3'"
alias 1s="sleep 1s && play ~/Desktop/shubhi/shubhi_songs/'Alarm Clock For Heavy Sleepers (Loud)-fpQHabt6e-w.mp3'"
alias m="cd ~/Desktop/shubhi/movies"


#shubhi functions:-


#1) function that creates directory folder and jump into it
mkcd ()
{
  mkdir -p -- "$1" && cd -P -- "$1"
}




# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/shubharthak/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/shubharthak/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/shubharthak/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/shubharthak/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Can somebody help me out. Surprisingly, there's no line number 217 in my .bashrc file, Am new here kindly help
Thank you

Comment: Hello, welcome to U&L. It seems the problem is in the `bash_completion` file, also because your `.bashrc` is only 183 lines long. Please edit your question to include the line #217 of `bash_completion` and its neighbouring lines

Comment: Do you also have a `~/.bash_aliases` file? If yes, what is its content? An alias named `do` is a good candidate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22969050/10488700

Comment: Hey Thank you my problem has been solved actually, I have included 2 blank lines because of which my .bashrc file gets messed up. Moreover, there's no 217th line, I only had 181 lines but I had 2 new blank lines too which made it 183. Anyway, Thank you for your response.

Comment: I rolled back your recent edit and tagging of the title with "SOLVED".  If you have an answer to your own question, consider adding it in the answer box below.  You may later accept your own answer which marks the issue as resolved. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Okay @Kusalananda thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think the problem in my .bashrc file was I added two extra blank lines at end of my file. My .bashrc file has 181 lines but including two extra lines made it 183. However, After removing both of the extra blank lines made my problem solved. Although, I have no idea why my terminal saying to check line 217 as I don't have 217th line in my .bashrc file.